# python -- for with an if statement

Tags: python, jira

I dont understand why, when i run my code the for each loop under the if statement isn't run.  Even when the number of found is greater than 0!

```
def findpattern(commit_msg):
    pattern = re.compile("\w\w*-\d\d*")
    group = pattern.finditer(commit_msg)
    found = getIterLength(group)
    print found
    if found > 0:
        issues = 0
        for match in group:
                print " print matched issues:"
                auth = soap.login(jirauser,passwd)

                print match.group(0)
                getIssue(auth,match.group(0))
                issues = issues + 1
    else: 
        sys.exit("No issue patterns found.")

print "Retrieved issues: " + str(issues)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have been banging my head on this for an hour.

Comment: What makes you think `found` is a number?

Comment: i am sure found is a number. :)

Comment: What IS getIterLength? And what values of found are you seeing?

Comment: I didn't ask if you were sure.  I asked what makes you think `found` is a number.  Please provide the actual evidence that `found` is a number so we can all be sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `getIterLength()` function is finding the length by exhausting the iterator returned by `finditer()`.  You would then need a new iterator instance for the for loop.  Instead, I would restructure your code like this:

```
def findpattern(commit_msg):
    pattern = re.compile("\w\w*-\d\d*")
    group = pattern.finditer(commit_msg)

    found = 0
    issues = 0
    for match in group:
        print " print matched issues:"
        auth = soap.login(jirauser,passwd)

        print match.group(0)
        getIssue(auth,match.group(0))
        issues = issues + 1
        found += 1
    if found == 0:
        sys.exit("No issue patterns found.")


    print "Retrieved issues: " + str(issues)
```

OR, you could use the `findall()` method instead of `finditer()` to give you a list (which is an iterable, not an iterator) on which you can run `len(group)` to get the size and then use it to iterate over in your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code formatting it looks like under the for you have a double tab instead of a single tab, remember python is very picky about indentation

Comment: i fixed the tabs. but still no mas.

Comment: It actually doesn't care if you use double tabs in one block and single tabs in another. As long as the indention level doesn't change unexpectedly in the middle of a block, it's good.

Comment: It may not matter to the interpreter, but python *programmers* are much pickier about indentation.